# Limit CPU usage for a script

Tags: python, unix, cpu-usage

Is it possible for a Python script to limit the CPU power allocated to it?

Right now, I have a script (using only one core) that is using 100% of one CPU's core. I need it to use less than that amount.

Is there an equivalent to PHP's `memory_limit` in Python? or is there a library to manage memory allocation? (using `sleep` isn't a very elegant solution)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe try Python's [`resource`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html) package?

The resource package is basically a wraparound of `setrlimit` in UNIX. So you can set constrains for CPU/Memory usage, etc.

[More about `setrlimit` in Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit)