# Control resources for multiple concurrent requests in flask

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing

When I set option `app.run(threaded=True))` in flask, my service can handle multiple concurrent requests. But it seems that my service will consume as much as possible CPU resources to handle multiple concurrent requests.
Is there anyway to limit or control resources used by my app?

Comment: My advice is to use a better wsgi server like uwsgi or gunicorn not the development server of flask, they both have options for controlling system resources

Comment: I tried gunicorn with options:
gunicorn --workers=4 -t 3000 myapp -b port.
I have no idea is it working in my case or not (I just want half of CPU resources are used for my service) because my service created about 8-10 processes when there're 4 requests.

Comment: My thought is then that the number of concurrent processes should be equal to half the number of cores your processor has. e.g. 2 processes on a 4-core CPU can only consume 50% of resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the resource module. Taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27920419/python-limit-cpu-usage-for-a-script). You would do something like this for the CPU. [Here is](https://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html) the page on the resource module.

```
import resource
sec = 60 * 60 # this is one hour of time.
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_CPU, sec)
```

Note, this changes the amount of time (in seconds) that the process is allowed on the CPU. If you want to limit the amount of stack/heap size of the process you must use `resource.RLIMIT_STACK` and `resource.RLIMIT_HEAP`. These are in bytes though, so the code would look something like this.

```
import resource
mem = 1024 * 1024 # this is one megabyte, you want much more than this normally
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_STACK, mem)
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_HEAP, mem)
```

Comment: Will this cause any conflict? since my service is multiprocessing, 4 processes are created to serve each request.

Comment: No, multiprocessing uses threads even though it may not look like it. A process is a single program, when the program starts another program it should start it as a thread. I may be wrong on this, you may have to just start it as a thread, I'm not sure how Python multiprocessing works. If it doesn't work then you can just do the same thing for each process, limiting the amount of resources they each have.

Comment: Actually a wsgi server (gunicorn) solved my problem.