# Prevent freezing when running python scripts from terminal

Tags: python, shell

I am running some python scripts in my linux terminal that happen to be pretty resource intensive, but when I do my system will become pretty non-responsive until the process has completed. I know there are commands like nice and cpulimit but I haven't found a great way to just open a terminal that is somehow resource limited (and what percentage of resources can be devoted to it) and can be used to run any scripts during that particular session.

So is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Limit cpu usage for a script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27920419/python-limit-cpu-usage-for-a-script)

Comment: @DenisOlehov I did see this post, but it was a bit sparse the details of how to actually address my issue.

Comment: have you opened a documentation?
https://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html#resource.setrlimit

Comment: @DenisOlehov I don't know how useful those would be to this question. The problem is probably CPU related and the only thing CPU related in the *resource* module is CPU time usage which I don't think Nightman is looking for. The others are concerned with various memory usage levels.

Comment: there is a method called `.setrlimit()` :/